# Android 7.0 One plus 3. How to remove the first user that was created

Tags: 7.0-nougat, multi-user

In my android phone I have two users (Settings -> users) : the first that was created (user A), has more rights than the second one (user B).

User A belonged to a previous owner of the phone, while User B is the one I currently use and I would like to keep.

How can I remove User A so that User B gets the privileges?

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK the only way to achieve that is a "fresh start" by performing a factory reset. But I might be wrong as I haven't been in such a situation yet to try it myself.

Comment: What are the privileges you are talking of -you can install apps, update existing apps on main user, delete apps ! If you are talking of phone calls and address book sharing *To enable or disable the phone and SMS functions for a secondary user, go to Settings > Users, select the user, and switch the Allow phone calls and SMS setting to off* . Unless you factory reset as @izzy suggested

Comment: @beeshyams Don is talking about the OWNER privileges. First user created is considered device owner. I've never read about a method to change the device owner – except for performing a factory reset, as then you start again with creating the first user. AFAIR only the device owner (aka "first user") can create or remove users. So what I don't get is why the "previous owner" was kept on device transfer – unless it's a parent, and that system was established as "child protection"; in which case Don would want to work around restrictions his parents set up ;)

Comment: @izzy: Family common phone was what I thought of too

Comment: If you can't get the original owner to sign out of the account, don't factory reset, you would be locked out, courtesy factory reset protection

Comment: I currently have access to both accounts, indeed the owner account was created by my father, the previous owner of the phone, sadly he passed away few months ago, I started using his phone when I lost mine, initially I didn't want to mess up with his contacts and photos, so I created a second account on the phone. I'm 38 so I wouldn't need any child protection anyways. I generally don't post such details on stackexchange, but since I was questioned, I thought I had to. I hope this clears my intentions. There are several features blocked on my account, tethering, and many configs among them.

Comment: I'd hoped there was a way to clean up this users mess, without a factory reset, I'd have to reinstall all my apps, and waste a half afternoon in the process..